# EU national living in UK: Do I need visa to travel to the Netherlands or to Iceland?

Tags: visas, uk, schengen-visas, polish-citizens, freedom-of-movement

I have a Polish passport. I am living in UK under the EU settlement scheme. Do I need a visa to go to either country? My intention is to attend a festival.

Comment: Polish citizens have had this right since Poland joined the EU on May 1st, 2004 -- the relevant directive took effect the day before.  Is it not widely known in Poland?

Answer (score 13):

Forget your UK status, as a Polish, and hence EU, citizen you can travel freely in the EU (e.g. Netherlands) and the EEA (e.g. Iceland).  You could even settle down in one of these countries.  Use your Polish passport and you will sail in.  I recently flew from Canada to Iceland.  Most of the flight went to the non-EU/EEA/CH queue.  I walked up an empty EU/EEA/CH self-scan gate and presented my Irish passport.  It took seconds.